# How to calculate the count among the multi-column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data format:

```
    col_a  col_b col_c
0    10     12     11
1     8      6     99
```

And I would like to be:

```
    col_a  col_b col_c   0-10   11-20 >20
0    10     12     11     1       2    0
1     8      6     99     2       0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean masks by conditions and count `True`s values by `sum`:

```
m1 = (df > 0) & (df <=10)
m2 = (df > 10) & (df <=20)
m3 = (df > 20)

df['0-10'] = m1.sum(axis=1) 
df['11-20'] = m2.sum(axis=1) 
df['>20'] = m3.sum(axis=1) 

print (df)
   col_a  col_b  col_c  0-10  11-20  >20
0     10     12     11     1      2    0
1      8      6     99     2      0    1
```

Solution with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is possible, but is necessary reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (pd.cut(df.stack(), 
              bins=[0,10,20, np.inf], 
              labels=['0-10','11-20','>20'])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .value_counts()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   col_a  col_b  col_c  0-10  11-20  >20
0     10     12     11     1      2    0
1      8      6     99     2      0    1
```

Comment: Hi, @jezrael, can't we do that with `pd.cut or pd.qcut` ?

Comment: @pyd - I think `pd.cut` or `pd.qcut` working with Series and binning, here is necessary count. so simpliest/fastest this. But I think possible